# What are the disadvantages/advantages of starting a program from UI Layer?

Tags: c#, .net

Recently, our Development team came up with an idea of reorganizing our processes. Aside from the new methodology that needs to be implemented, our consultant suggested that we should start our development from UI layer and release it weekly for user testing even if the backbone is not yet completed. His idea is that, we need to release a module as quickly as possible in weekly bases. According to him, the users do not really mind what's behind the application, their concern is only about the output of the application (i totally agree with Him on this). Although I am not totally convinced with the idea of starting from UI Layer as I tend to start coding either from the application's domain or the Database instead of doing the UI Design. I don't know if I am just being bias here.

Any thoughts, ideas or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: how will the UI perform anything meaningful during the user test if `backbone is not ready`?

Comment: It appears to be a reorganisation, so the backbone already exists.

Comment: By dealing with the UI, you can focus on what the users actually want to achieve. However this is a double edged sword, as it can also lead to you focusing on implementation details of GUIs instead of business flows i.e. UX lead vs DDD style.

Comment: @muratgu - have raised the same question but some of my co-dev suggested to develop the backbone per UI demand. For example, your task is to create the login module, then you will need to design the login UI then its code behind up to the database or even if the database is not yet ready you can just hard code the data as long as the login function is addressed.

Comment: I disagree - every time I have ever released do-nothing UIs to get feedback, the first comment is that it doesn't do anything - even with savvy users.  It *can* work, but for the most part their perspective is the business elements and how well the app helps them do their job.  Only after they are  able to create widget orders are there worthwhile feedback of *we need this, can we have a foo button....* etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question, not knowing your development/sale structures.

I've expierienced this kind of points very often, resulting in a not-maintainable whatever (The result had nothing to with software anymore)

Modern development will mostly fail without an strategy like **Scrum** or **Agile**.

Consultants and sales-department often push in that direction because they want to sell stuff and get therefore money in their own pocket due to provision. Usually they have nothing bad in their mind. They simply just dont know it better and probably have never heard about Softwarearchitecture before.

Anyway, following some points on pros and cons:

**Pro**

- Sales-Dudes can sell products better because they have something to show to the customer
- Users/Customers can get an early feel for the Application and can point out what they like and what you have to improve

**Cons**

- Hardly you will be able to follow architectonical patterns (MVVM just to name one)
- Mosty you produce non-maintainable-code
- In most cases your application will not be extensible (Plugins)
- Sales-Dudes and Users usually dont know what they even want, ending up in applications like [this](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Classic_WTF_-_Enter_the_Matrix)
- Your code will be really hard to test. So [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) will not be possible

These are only a few examples stuck in my mind. I could extend this list to 4 pages why it is **NOT** a reasonable idea to develop by UI-First.

I know this is mostly based on my opinion, but its also full of Expierence i made by myself, resulting in developing the same Application over and over again.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts, the listed cons is what I am worried about. Knowing our dev guys here, mostly junior dev, I am pretty sure the idea is not advisable.